# Tying the result of web service call back to the calling function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-services

I'm probably missing something simple but given this JS code:

```
var WS = {
    whoami: function () {
        var toReturn;
        $.getJSON("/SecurityData/GetCurrentUser", function (data) {
            toReturn = data.Email;
        });

        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

When I call it, if I put a breakpoint on the `toReturn = data.Email`, the expected data is there but if don't `WS.whoami` is undefined.

I assume this is because the `$.getJSON` call is async, but how can I get the desired effect?

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is asynchronous and returns a promise object. Instead, return the promise object and add a callback to it.

```
var WS = {
    whoami: function () {
        return $.getJSON("/SecurityData/GetCurrentUser");
    }
};

WS.whoami().done(function(data){
    alert(data.Email);
});
```

The only other option would be to make it a synchronous request, however I do not recommend it due to the impact it will have on your UX. You would have to use `$.ajax` and `async:false`

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to call your function with a callback. This way, your code stays async, and continues when the json call is complete.

```
var WS = {
    whoami: function (callback) {
        $.getJSON("/SecurityData/GetCurrentUser", callback);
    }
}

WS.whoami(function(data) {
    // code that uses var data 
});
```